# How to group items in list using lables inside items?

Tags: python, list, named-entity-recognition

There is list like :

```
list_a = [('B-DATE', '07'),('I-DATE', '/'),('I-DATE', '08'),('I-DATE', '/'),('I-DATE', '20'),('B-LAW', 'Abc'),('I-LAW', 'def'),('I-LAW', 'ghj'),('I-LAW', 'klm')]
```

I need to get joined `list_a[x][1]` items according to `list_a[x][0]` labels: "start with letter B" and all to the next "B-started"-label (`list_a[x][0]`):

```
list_b = ['07/08/20','Abcdefghjklm']
```

Like using stringagg + groupby in Oracle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One Line Solution

Here is a one line answer using **list-comprehension**. The *trick* is to use a distinctly identifiable separator (I used `'|||'`) prepended to the *value* that appears with each new occurrence of `'B'`.

```py
str(''.join([f'|||{v}' if k.startswith("B") else v for (k, v) in list_a])).split('|||')[1:]
```

**Output**:

```
['07/08/20', 'Abcdefghjklm']
```

> **Algorithm**
>
> 1. Create a list of values where the values corresponding to each new occurrence of `'B'` are preceded by `'|||'`.
> 2. Join all the items in the list into a single string.
> 3. Split the string by the separator, `'|||'`.
> 4. Keep all but the first element for the `str.split()`.

Comment: @luliia How about this?

Comment: Awesome!!!! You're really python-guru! Thanks a lot! When I achieve 15 reputation, you'll get my voice :)

Comment: @luliia Glad I could help! Could you please **`accept`** and **`upvote`** the answer as well? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using a simple iteration with `str.startswith`.

**Ex:**

```
list_a = [('B-DATE', '07'),('I-DATE', '/'),('I-DATE', '08'),('I-DATE', '/'),('I-DATE', '20'),('B-LAW', 'Abc'),('I-LAW', 'def'),('I-LAW', 'ghj'),('I-LAW', 'klm')]
res = []
for k, v in list_a:
    if k.startswith("B"):   #Check starts with `B`
        res.append(v)
    else:
        res[-1]+= v
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['07/08/20', 'Abcdefghjklm']
```

Comment: I hoped it could be done without loops. Maybe some lambda-functions + itertools :(

Comment: i do not think a loop can be avoided since you have a `list` of tuples

Comment: @Rakesh You can do it in a single line using list-comprehension. Since, I modified your answer and found yours to be most pythonic among others, I also voted you up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below :

```
        output = []
        for obj in list_a:
            if obj[0].startswith('B'):
                output.append(obj[1])
            else:
                output[-1] += obj[1]
        print(output)
```

Comment: I hoped it could be done without loops. Maybe some lambda-functions + itertools :(

Answer (score 0):

This is my variant, but I hope there is more "modern" way to do it on python:

```
list_b = []
for i in range(len(list_a)):
    if list_a[i][0][0] == 'B':
      list_b += [list_a[i][1]]
    else:
      list_b[len(list_b)-1] += list_a[i][1]    
print(list_b)
```